# find and replace a substring and change to uppercase

Tags: find, string, replace

I think it's best done with an example

**Contents of my file**

```
name="apple" parameter1="value1" parameter2="value2";
name="orange" parameter1="value1" parameter2="value2";
name="tea" parameter1="value1" parameter2="value2";
name="whatever" parameter1="value1" parameter2="value2";
```

I want to convert apple/orange/tea/whatever to uppercase and saved it back to the same file or a new one.

Any ideas on how it can be done? Thanks

edit:

- all contents in the file are included but at the moment **there are no lines that will be exluded**.
- Also, the text "name" has no quotes around it. It is saved as written above.

Comment: Are there commented out versions, and should they be changed or not? Can names have quoted in them, and how?

Comment: @JeffSchaller no comments and names have no quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{q=toupper(substr($1, 6)); printf ("name=%s %s %s\n", q, $2, $3)}' filename
```